# Script ran successfully but still software is not uninstalled

Tags: windows, powershell, uninstallation, powershell-4.0

> Even though the below script runs successfully to remove software, I
> am still able to see the software in the control panel program list,
> what I am doing wrong?

See the command below :

> PS D:\Project>  .\ScriptWithBelowCode.ps1 -ComputerName
> "X-XXX50947" -AppGUID XXXXXX-A60B-4899-A369-XXXXXXX
> Uninstallation command triggered successfully

```
[cmdletbinding()]            

param (            

 [parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
 [string]$ComputerName = $env:computername,
 [parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,Mandatory=$true)]
 [string]$AppGUID
)            

 try {
  $returnval = ([WMICLASS]"\\$computerName\ROOT\CIMV2:win32_process").Create("msiexec `/x$AppGUID `/norestart `/qn")
 } catch {
  write-error "Failed to trigger the uninstallation. Review the error message"
  $_
  exit
 }
 switch ($($returnval.returnvalue)){
  0 { "Uninstallation command triggered successfully" }
  2 { "You don't have sufficient permissions to trigger the command on $Computer" }
  3 { "You don't have sufficient permissions to trigger the command on $Computer" }
  8 { "An unknown error has occurred" }
  9 { "Path Not Found" }
  9 { "Invalid Parameter"}
 }


Command to execute .\ScriptFileWithAboveContent.ps1 -ComputerName "X-15XX150947" -AppGUID 30F836D2-A60B-4899-A369-XXXXX884EAF


Command to get GUID 
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product ` -Filter "Name like '%Microsoft%'" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty IdentifyingNumber
```

***Second try***

```
$app = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Where-Object {$_.IdentifyingNumber -match "XXXXXX-A60B-4899-XXXX-B0FXXX84EAF" }
    $app.Uninstall()
```

I am getting error showing below

```
 PS D:\Project> .\ScriptFileWithAboveContent.ps1
    Exception calling "Uninstall" : "Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object."
    At D:\MicrosoftAIM\ScriptFileWithAboveContent.ps1:2 char:5
    +     $app.Uninstall()
    +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WMIMethodException
```

***Third try***

The below script ran successfully, But still, the software is still in the program list.

```
echo "Getting product code"
$ProductCode = Get-WmiObject win32_product -Filter "Name like '%somesoftware%'" | Select-Object -Expand IdentifyingNumber
echo "removing Product"
# Out-Null argument is just for keeping the power shell command window waiting for msiexec command to finish else it moves to execute the next echo command
& msiexec /x $ProductCode | Out-Null
echo "uninstallation finished"


PS D:\MicrosoftAIM> .\ScriptWithAboveContent.ps1
Getting product code
removing Product
uninstallation finished
PS D:\MicrosoftAIM> Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product ` -Filter "Name like '%Microsoft%azure%info%'"
```

Comment: _software is not uninstalled_ and _still able to see the software in the control panel program list_ are two different things - **is** the software uninstalled?

Comment: no it is not uninstalled, its there already

Comment: alright, i got your point, then how do remove this from the program list?

Comment: I'd suggest updating the question accordingly.

Comment: But still i am able to see the software in my Get-Package even though it present in program list

Comment: Does that mean it is uninstalled ?